# How to add columns optionally per section

Tags: two-column, multicol

How would I add optional columns under a section. e.g. (fyi image from a random online resume):

[image]

So if I decide to remove any of the years listed, the text should not shift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it simply with a `description` environment and with the help of the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Education}

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries,leftmargin=1.5cm,style=sameline]
  \item[1996] Doctor of Philosophy
  \item[1986] Master of Science
  \item[1982] Bachelor of Science
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Now delete `1996` from the above code, so to have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{Education}

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries,leftmargin=1.5cm,style=sameline]
  \item[] Doctor of Philosophy
  \item[1986] Master of Science
  \item[1982] Bachelor of Science
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

and you will have the following output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `paracol` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
Education
\columnratio{0.2,0.8}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    1996\\
    ~\\
    1983\\
\switchcolumn
    University A\\ 
    University B\\
    Univertity C\\
\end{paracol}
Professional Experience
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make your code compilable, complete with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`?